# A window does not fit to display in WPF 2010

Tags: xaml

I have a window. Its property is:

```
    <Window x:Class="Student.MainWindow" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"        
    Title="MainWindow" Height="996" Width="1191" 
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Student"             
    Loaded="Window_Loaded"        
    WindowState="Maximized">
```

When this window is run in “Windows XP” then the windows is shown fully, correctly. But if the window is opened in “Windows 7” then height of the window is not okay, however the width is normal. Height is bigger than display and the bottom of the window is not fitted in a display. I would like that the window will be in display and will not be larger than the height of a display in “Windows 7”.
How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just decreased a height of a window and it helps my window to fit properly:).

```
<Window x:Class="Student.MainWindow" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"        
Title="MainWindow" Height="850" Width="1191" 
xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Student"             
Loaded="Window_Loaded"        
WindowState="Maximized">
```